# how to modify json array object

Tags: javascript, json

i have JSON array object coming as request with many fields. I have to send backend request with only limited fields how to achieve this using javascript.

This is how the request look like

```
{
   
   "Items":[
      {
         "ItemId":"1",
         "manufacturingNo": "Y23",
         "catalogID": "123",
         "quantity":2
         
      },
      {
         "ItemId":"2",
         "manufacturingNo": "Y33",
         "catalogID": "23",
         "quantity":29
         
      }
   ]
}
```

Required request is

```
{
   
   "viewItems":[
      {
         "ItemId":"1",
         "quantity":2
         
      },
      {
         "ItemId":"2",
         "quantity":29
         
      }
   ]
}
```

how to loop through and achieve this

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should make an attempt to solve this yourself first using [available documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) to [help you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array = {
   
   "Items":[
      {
         "ItemId":"1",
         "manufacturingNo": "Y23",
         "catalogID": "123",
         "quantity":2
         
      },
      {
         "ItemId":"2",
         "manufacturingNo": "Y33",
         "catalogID": "23",
         "quantity":29
         
      }
   ]
}
const result = {
    viewItems: array.Items.map((item) => ({ ItemId: item.ItemId, quantity: item.quantity  }))
}
console.log(result)
```